Can't seem to obtain block group level information from 2010 census
I'm trying to obtain voting age population information from the 2010 decennial census via the Census API. I can't seem to access data finer than tracts though, since the following example query works
https://api.census.gov/data/2010/dec/sf1?get=GEO_ID,P011001,P011002&for=tract:*&in=state:22
but when I swap out tract for block_group, it gives me an error. I would think I could access block group level information since the 2010 census has a block and block group variable. Am I using the wrong identifier for block groups? Can I not access block group level information for some particular reason? Or am I wrong and there really isn't the information I want at that geographic granularity?

Nest the hierarchy get=GEO_ID,NAME,P011001,P011002&for=block:&in=state:22&in=county:&in=tract:* See example 100 in the API doc
